# sprintf - формирование нескольких подсрок с использованием одного параметра

Tags: c++, c, printf, format, sprintf

Подскажите, можно ли реализовать следующую задумку:

```
int var1, var2;

sprintf(buffer, "%d1 %d2 --- #d1 $d2", var1, var2);
```

т.е. чтобы где `%d1` использовался `var1`, а где `%d2` - `var2`

Просто, чтобы не писать трудночитаемые многобуквенные конструкции типа

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d %d --- #d $d", var1, var2, var1, var2);
```

Comment: В стандартном C/С++ такого нет, а вот в `boost` есть  https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.format

Comment: @AlexanderChernin , а с помощью `std::bind` и смежных средств этого не сделать?

Comment: Можно, конечно. Например, с помощью variadic templates или va_list

Comment: @cpp questions, это как?

Comment: @Zhihar передавать переменное число аргументов в функцию, по мере чтения строки подставлять вместо %di i-ый переданный аргумент